# Erro CS0847 em código de matriz em C#

Tags: c#, array, .net, inicialização

Estou fazendo um código simples de matriz em C# para exibir valores em string, só que aparece **Erro CS0847: Inicializador de matriz de comprimento "3"** na linha 9 e não entendi o que significa.

```
using System;

namespace TesteMatriz1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] lista = new string[3, 3] { { "Dante", "Sparda" }, { "Vergil", "Sparda" }, { "Nero", "Sparda" } };

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Nome: {lista[i, j]}");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significa que você está criando um matriz 3 x 3 e está inicializando ela com menos elementos, no caso de forma bem clara está fazendo 3 x 2, se o que deseja é uma matriz assim, então determine o tamanho correto, assim:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace TesteMatriz1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var lista = new string[3, 2] { { "Dante", "Sparda" }, { "Vergil", "Sparda" }, { "Nero", "Sparda" } };
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) WriteLine($"Nome: {lista[i, j]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Ou deixe o compilador assumir o tamanho, assim:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace TesteMatriz1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var lista = new string[,] { { "Dante", "Sparda" }, { "Vergil", "Sparda" }, { "Nero", "Sparda" } };
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) WriteLine($"Nome: {lista[i, j]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VZ4XrJ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OZAIrA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/MatrixInitialization.cs).

Comment: Porque esses dois for´s juntos e porque substituiu o string lista por var lista?

Comment: Porque eu gosto de escrever menos código quando faz sentido.

Comment: Como eu posso substituir essa gambiarra de `Nome ({i},{j}): {lista[i, j]}` para mostrar `Nome (0,0): Dante, Nome(0,1): Nero`, ou do jeito que fiz está correto?

Comment: Se é o que deseja está correto.

Comment: Como faço para unir alguns elementos da matriz na mesma linha: por exemplo: Dante Sparda é uma pessoa e não duas, em uma linha aparece Dante e na outra Sparda.

Comment: Depende **exatamente** como quer, mas isso é outra pergunta, tente fazer, se não der certo abra uma pergunta nova.

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Você definiu que a `array` `lista` seja do tamanho 3x3 mas definiu ela sendo apenas como 3x2.
Adicionando mais um nome a cada índice você resolveria o seu problema. Ou você pode diminuir a definição para `new string[3, 2]`

Eu recomendo que acesse uma `array` sem ser com índices máximos `hard-coded`.
No seu caso, por exemplo, se a `array`, por um acaso, mudasse para 2x2, você teria problemas de `array out of bounds` que seria índice fora do limite. Você estaria tentando acessar o índice 3 quando ele nem existe.

Você pode primeiramente deixar o compilador atribuir um tamanho a sua array assim:

```
string[,] lista = new string[,] { { "Dante", "Sparda" }, { "Vergil", "Sparda" }, { "Nero", "Sparda" } };
```

E para iterar sempre atingindo o máximo, mesmo que a array mude, assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lista.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Nome: {lista[i, j]}");
    }
}
```

O `.GetLength(int)` vai pegar o tamanho da array. No seu caso, como é bidimensional teremos o `GetLength(0)` e `GetLength(1)`.

Comment: `GetLength(int)` vai me ajudar e muito pra não precisar ficar digitando tamanho de array.

Comment: É possível colocar `GetLength(int)` em um vetor e em uma matriz onde o usuário deve digitar valores?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua colocação. Acredito que talvez seja melhor uma outra pergunta a respeito. E porque não usar Listas?